# Iperf tool cannot set one larger socket buffer

Tags: linux, iperf3

Recently I try Iperf3 to test our system's throughput. I want to set tcp's window size to 2M, but failed.

*iperf3 -c 135.242.61.60 -w 2M*

*Connecting to host 135.242.61.60, port 5201*

*iperf3: error - socket buffer size not set correctly*

I check iperf3's source code, and find out that iperf3 will setsockopt with parameter 2M and then getsockopt to verify the paramter. The value getsockopt return is less than 2M. I think maybe there are some limitation in Kernel.

How can I enlarge the tcp window to 2M?

Comment: I've tested it myself and it worked. This GitHub issue seems to be related to your problem. https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/757#issuecomment-401173762

Comment: Please mark the question as answered then